# whatsapp share link url not showing even description and thumbnail magento 1.9

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, whatsapp

whatsapp share link preview not showing even description and thumbnail magento 1.9 but working on twitter pinterest and facebook..help 
here is my meta

```
"<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>original leather - kerajinan kulit - jogjakarta Srikandi 511</title>
<meta name="description" content="satu kantong utama memanjang
card sleeves
Bahan : Kulit pull Up
9 x 2 x 18
 0.5 Kg
">
<meta name="keywords" content="originalleather, kerajinankulit, taskulit, dompetkulit, kulit, souvenirkulit, yogyakarta">
<meta name="robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW">


<!--- facebook card -->

<meta property="og:title" content="Srikandi 511">
<meta property="og:type" content="product">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://pamoor.com/srikandi-511.html">
<meta property="og:description" content="satu kantong utama memanjang
card sleeves
Bahan : Kulit pull Up
9 x 2 x 18
 0.5 Kg
">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Default Store View">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="500">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="500">
<meta property="og:image" itemprop="image" content="https://pamoor.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/i/m/img_6604.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" itemprop="image" content="https://pamoor.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/i/m/img_6604.jpg">
<!--- whatsap card -->

<!--- twitter card -->
 <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
 <meta name="twitter:site" content="Default Store View">
 <meta name="twitter:title" content="Srikandi 511">
 <meta name="twitter:description" content="satu kantong utama memanjang
card sleeves
Bahan : Kulit pull Up
9 x 2 x 18
 0.5 Kg
">
 <meta name="twitter:image" content="https://pamoor.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/i/m/img_6604.jpg">"
```

anyone can help ?

it's my website 
[pamoor](https://pamoor.com)

Comment: can you tell me which extension you are using for whatsapp share?

Comment: im not using any exstension for whatsapp share...

Comment: tried just copy and paste url to whatsapp still no description no image thumbnail, just address swhoing no preview

Comment: I think that's not working you have customization in your code

Comment: It is showing images and description when I am sharing this url https://pamoor.com/srikandi-511.html

Comment: yeahh thanks for helping me jinesh...i tried to change with default header code..but still not working :D :D:D finally i gave up :D :D:D ..

ohh yeah maybe my whatsapp cache or website chache okay ill'try...bezo both of them not working thanks alot jinesh

Comment: But it is working when I am sharing url

Comment: thanks jinesh finally i asked my friend to share whatsapp link to me...and as u said it's working... i gues it's my isp problem... thanks jiness... regards

Comment: okay contact ISP provider